# My bike key is broken off inside the lock

Tags: lock

My bike key is broken off inside the lock, I already remove the key from the lock but I have no backup key to unlock it.

It is a very ordinary key, just like this:

[image]

Is there any way to unlock my bike? Will the brick or a saw be helpful?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a cable lock like in the image. If so, bolt cutters. You'll be surprised and dismayed to see how easily you can cut a cable lock with a set of bolt cutters (maybe enough to invest in a better quality lock?)

Comment: @WTHarper maybe make that an answer instead of a comment?  Then your answer can be voted up -- you get reputation, and this question no longer shows up on the "unanswered" page.

Comment: Yeah, if you're not trying to save the lock, bolt cutters are the best choice -- will cut through that cable in about 30 seconds.  You can buy a pair cheaply at places like Harbor Freight in the US, or maybe rent a pair at a tool rental shop.  And don't be too worried about using them "in public", since tests have shown that people just ignore bike thieves 90% of the time.  (But do make sure you have your ID on you.)  But if you want to save the lock you need to pick it or get a locksmith to do so.  Not rocket science, for a standard pin tumbler lock.  A locksmith can then cut you a new key.

Comment: And as Benzo said in a deleted answer, you can more slowly cut through the cable with ordinary wire cutters, a few strands at a time.  This might take 15 minutes or so, though, and will leave you with bleeding knuckles.

Comment: Unless it's a very expensive lock, the locksmith would probably cost you more than a new lock.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it a cable lock like in the image? If so, bolt cutters. You'll be surprised and dismayed to see how easily you can cut a cable lock with a set of bolt cutters (maybe enough to invest in a better quality lock?) They're cheap, easy to find, and will get through most wire cable and some chain (depending on hardness.) They're also the go-to for most bike thieves, so don't be overly conspicuous about using them.

[image: Bolt Cutters]

Comment: Yeah, if it's a cheap lock, just about any tool will do. Bolt cutters, hacksaw, Dremel with a cutting disc, hammer (to the locking mechanism), vice grips, wire ships (for cable locks).  You can be creative.

Comment: A hatchet, a sharp rock, a pry bar...the list goes on, unfortunately.

Comment: IMO a hacksaw blade, warped in a newspaper for a handle, is the cheapest solution. Guaranteed to work in under a minute.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a hacksaw but don't own bolt cutters, it only takes a few minutes to cut through the cable with a hacksaw. Just grip the cable with a pair of pliers, then use the hacksaw to cut the cable near the pliers - the hacksaw cuts through the individual cable strands quickly. When I lost my cable lock key, it took me less than 5 minutes to cut off my 3/8"  cable lock with a hacksaw. Would probably have taken less time if I had someone else to hold the pliers.